# Eclipse - JFace table columns not displaying in custom dialog

Tags: java, eclipse, swt, jface

I'm making a custom dialog with JFace but having trouble with my columns not displaying. Here's my code. All I get is the table with no columns and a blue line to the left. This extends JFace dialog.

```
@Override
protected Control createDialogArea(Composite parent)
{
  Composite container = (Composite) super.createDialogArea(parent);

  container.setLayout(new GridLayout());

  addTableToDialog(container);

  container.getShell().setSize(600, 400);

  return container;
 }


private void addTableToDialog(Composite container)
{
   _tableViewer = new TableViewer(container, SWT.MULTI | SWT.H_SCROLL |  SWT.V_SCROLL | SWT.FULL_SELECTION | SWT.BORDER);
   _tableViewer.getTable().setHeaderVisible(true);
   _tableViewer.getTable().setLinesVisible(true);
   _tableViewer.getTable().setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, true));

  renderHeaders();
}
```

private void renderHeaders()
    {

```
  int bound = 1;

  for (int header = 0; header < _headers.length; header++)
  {
     String tableHeader = _headers[header];
     createTableViewerColumn(tableHeader, bound);
  }

}


private TableViewerColumn createTableViewerColumn(String title, int bound)
{
   final TableViewerColumn viewerColumn = new  TableViewerColumn(_tableViewer, SWT.NONE);
   final TableColumn tableColumn = viewerColumn.getColumn();

  tableColumn.setText(title);
  tableColumn.setResizable(true);
  tableColumn.setMoveable(true);

  _tableColumnLayout.setColumnData(tableColumn, new ColumnWeightData(bound));

  return viewerColumn;

 }
```

Comment: Where are you defining `_tableColumnLayout`? If this is `TableColumnLayout` that requires to be set on a `Composite` with thetable as its single child.

Comment: Thanks Greg, I was defining the `TableColumnLayout` in the constructor. I changed this to locally defining it when I'm creating the table viewer. When creating a `Composite` to hold the table, I was setting the layout to `GridLayout()`, but changed this to the `TableColumnLayout` and it now works. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

The following solved this problem for me. I define the TableColumnLayout when I'm creating the TableViewer and set this as the layout for a composite that contains the table.

```
private void addTableToDialog(Composite container)
{
  TableColumnLayout tableColumnLayout = new TableColumnLayout();

  Composite tableContainer = new Composite(container, SWT.NONE);
  tableContainer.setLayout(tableColumnLayout);
  tableContainer.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, true));

  _tableViewer = new TableViewer(tableContainer, SWT.MULTI | SWT.H_SCROLL | SWT.V_SCROLL | SWT.FULL_SELECTION | SWT.BORDER);
  _tableViewer.getTable().setHeaderVisible(true);
  _tableViewer.getTable().setLinesVisible(true);

  renderHeaders(tableColumnLayout);
}
```